# Strange ajax behavior with Zepto and Cordova

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, zepto

Something strange is going on with an Ajax call I'm making and I can't figure out why its happening, maybe someone can shed some light.

This is the call

```
$.ajax({type:'POST', url: apiURL+"misc/"+cola, headers: {'apikey':localStorage.apiKey}, dataType: 'html', success:function(data) {
    $("#pagina").html(data);
    postCarga("pagina");
}, error: function() {
    sinConexion();
}});
```

Now, this should take the "data" received from Ajax and fill div#pagina with it, but the div stays empty.

Here's the strange part, I called console.log(data) to see if the data is getting through and then it not only logs to the console but properly fills in the div#pagina with the returned data.

If I just try to fill it in directly, the div stays empty, but if I do anything beforehand (even something like var xxx = data;), it gets filled in correctly.

I worked around it by moving the filler function into postCarga so my final code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({type:'POST', url: apiURL+"misc/"+cola, headers: {'apikey':localStorage.apiKey}, dataType: 'html', success:function(data) {
    postCarga(data,"pagina");
}, error: function() {
    sinConexion();
}});
```

,but that feels strange.

// EDIT //
Here's the whole function

```
function postCarga(datos,que) {
    $("#"+que).html(datos).animate({top:'0%'},350,'ease-in',function() { $("#cargando").css("display","none"); });
}
```

,originally, all it did was animate and then hide the loader, the html(datos) is part of my fix.

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of `postCarga` in your listing? Just the lines that populate the div. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just found the reason. I was testing out different things by side-stepping the received data and just trying $("#pagina").html("Hello") and other things, after all of those worked I went trough the html returned by the Ajax call and that's where I found the answer.

I changed the return from the API to send just

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

and it worked fine, afterwards I manually built up the whole HTML string until I had a carbon copy of what the script generated, sometimes it would load and sometimes not, which was stranger still.

I passed the returned HTML through various lints and checkers and only one of them returned an error, one of the images in the block returned a 404, so I removed that image (and only that image) from the returned HTML and it loaded fine.

In essence, it seems that when Ajax is set to html (dataType: 'html'), each and every thing - direct or remote - in the entire block must be valid html and return a success when called, or it will be silently ignored.

Changing dataType to "text" makes it skip that check and just inject everything into the div as intended.